# IOS Scroll issue

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css, iphone

On our website, we have a full width video (HTML5 video tag). It works fine on desktop but on iphone when scrolling, the video disappears, then when stopped scrolling, it will show again. To make it clear, when scrolling, the section just a blank white space.

Comment: It would be useful if you could supply your code for this example.

Comment: If your video or it's container has the property `fixed`, please see this resource: [Safari Scroll issues with Fixed Content](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2015/jun/05/ipad-scroll-issues-with-fixed-content)

Comment: Read this content on [-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch does not "obey" z-index](https://github.com/scottjehl/Device-Bugs/issues/14)

Comment: Read generally about the wonders (issues) faced when scrolling on IOS browsers [Issues with position fixed & scrolling on iOS](https://remysharp.com/2012/05/24/issues-with-position-fixed-scrolling-on-ios)

Comment: I just noticed that when i scroll, the video keeps getting back to start.

Comment: `<video class="w-100" playsinline="" autoplay="" muted="" loop="" id="section-video--1556253067963" style="object-fit: cover;min-height:100vh" src="https://cdn2.shopify.com/s/files/1/0084/0944/8525/files/Video_for_website_1.mp4?28798">
                <source src="https://cdn2.shopify.com/s/files/1/0084/0944/8525/files/Video_for_website_1.mp4?28798" type="video/mp4">
            </video>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually is a browser compatibility issue.